# Why won't my computer boot?

Tags: boot, motherboard, troubleshooting

My computer was not booting any more (black screen, no beeps). I tried to remove the RAM and boot and again, black screen, no beeps. Does that mean that my motherboard is dead?

I have an old ASUS A8V delux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Did you have a PC Speaker wired or a sound card of some sort?

  - If your speaker path is not ready at boot up, the beeps would not be heard

    - the board has AC'97 Realtek audio
      (I assume you are using that and not a secondary card)
      Confirm that the speaker path is wired
  - If you have wired your speaker from the green jack on the port cluster that should be good
    (refer to the bottom of the ASUS review link below to see what I mean).
- The [ASUS A8V Deluxe](http://techreport.com/articles.x/7270/2) is a good board; would not expect bad components

  - however, that does not preclude a capacitor problem due to bad power or age
  - So, do check for blown capacitors
- The **board has a green LED** (left-bottom on the link above),

  - **does it light up when you try to boot**?
  - If it does not light up, you have a power path problem (the PSU or board power devices)
- Your first target should be to reconfirm all hardware on the board is properly seated

  - this would be the memory sticks and cards
  - you want to get back to the **beeps** or a **BIOS screen**

Comment: @Drahakar, Good to see you seem to have solved your problem. Would you update your root-cause-analysis under your question? It can help others.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things. It is usually Memory out of place (which you said you already checked for) or PSU Voltage Drop (Under performing).

One thing that is also likely and unfortunately nothing you can do about, check for dead / blown capacitors.

[image]

The top should be almost flat (with slight indents out embossed sections depending on specification... look at the middle one) but you do not want to see any big bumps such as the first one or any leakage as the last one.

If your pc is of the P4 generation, there were MANY MANY boards that had this problem which lead to a lot of random failures as you are experiencing now. I had this problem frequently after just 6 months of heavy usage.